# Advance Custom Field unable to show values in custom page template wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

Custom "single.php" unable to show Advance Custom Field value.

this is the function for getting the page id of custom "page template" using custom "single.php"

```
enter code here

<?php
  function lang_page_id($id){
    if(function_exists('icl_object_id')) 
    {
      return icl_object_id($id,'page', false,ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE);
    } else 
    {
     return $id;
    }
   }
?>
```

this for showing the acf value

```
enter code here

<h4 class="x-feature-box-title"><?php the_field('smr_header', 
lang_page_id(355));?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the following:

```
<?php
    function lang_page_id($id){
       if(function_exists('icl_object_id')) 
       {
           return icl_object_id($id,'page', false,ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE);
       } else 
       {
           return $id;
       }
    }
?>
```

In your code:

```
<h4 class="x-feature-box-title"><?php the_field('smr_header', 355);?>
```

Or:

```
<?php $h4_feature_title = get_field('smr_header', 355);?>
<h4 class="x-feature-box-title"><?php echo $h4_feature_title;?></h4>
```

ACF already has post specific values, simply put the id of the post that you want to get the field from. I am not sure why you would want to use this for the current page since then you should just use the_field('smr_header'); as this gets it from the current page.

If you do want to get the ID of the page, inside the loop:

```
$postid = get_the_ID();
echo $postid;
```

And only include on the custom page template.

If you do want to get the ID of the page, outside the loop, make a function with the following in:

```
global $wp_query;
echo $wp_query->post->ID;
```

Comment: Can you post your custom page template code (the whole thing) for me to take a look at. Or put it in a pastebin for me.

Comment: thanks daniel, it works, my mistake is I echo the id in the wrong template page that's why it gives me different id value.

Comment: Awesome glad I could help!